# Need to replace content of a line if particular string is found (lot of places )in a file, to replace with string also pattern in order

Tags: python

Eg:FileContains
**TextAA**
Content
**TextXy**
Content
**TextXX**

Expected:
**Text1**
Content
**Text2**
Content
**Text3**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello Sir, Sorry for not providing more info. Eg. I have a file content where "TextXX" (XX is numeric) is almost 600 places, i have rearranged and added further more "TextXX" in the middle. It requires manual work to change the order in series again "Text1", "Text2" to "Text600"
I have explored sed command (Dont have prior knowledge in python or shell)
sed -i '/Text/c (Text)' 
But it changes in all the places. Tried while and for, but not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')

for x in f:
    
    count = 0
    
    l = x.split()

    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        
        if 'Text' in x:
            count += 1
            l[i] = ''.join(["Text", str(count)])
            
    s = ' '.join(l)

    with open('output.txt', 'a') as output:
        output.write(s + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think, the question i have posted doesnt provided clarity. I have provided TextAA as an example. My requirement "TextXX" (XX is numeric) and not in a series in a file. (Almost 500- 600 places) . So I need to make a script, whenever i find "Text", the rest should be number in order , Text1, Text2,Text3... Etc

Comment: Thanks, will check it and let you know.

Comment: @VinothSundharam If the answer solves your issue, then please accept it.